# how to prevent access directly to my files in php

Tags: php, xml, xslt

hello everyone how to prevent access directly to my files.

My scenario is :

i have `<a  href="/book/mybook.pdf" download="/book/mybook.pdf">`  when i click on my file gets uploaded, but when i tab [www.mysite.com/book/mybook.pdf](http://www.mysite.com/book/mybook.pdf) i can access to the book without authentication.

i want to prevent access directly to my folder /book/* and my download still working.

btw i don't have .htaccess file but i have web.config

Answer (score 0):

i add filtring to my web.config

```
 <security>
 
           <requestFiltering>
               <fileExtensions>
                   <add fileExtension=".pdf" allowed="false" />
               </fileExtensions>
           </requestFiltering> 
       </security>
```

but now i cant download files too :(